# A scalar field satisfying the Laplace's Equation is zero everywhere

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, tensor-products, tensors, linear-pde

Q: A scalar field $A(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ is equal to zero on a closed surface $S$ in $\mathcal{R}$. If $A$ satisfies the Laplace equation $A_{,ii}=0$ in $\mathcal{R}$, show that $A=0$ everywhere in $\mathcal{R}$.

I have to show the above statement is true using tensor notations. To me it looks like solving a differential equation that is
\begin{align*}
A&=0\qquad\text{on } S\subset\mathcal{R}=\mathbb{R}^3\\
\nabla^2A&=0\qquad\text{in }\mathcal{R}=\mathbb{R}^3\\
\end{align*}

Is my idea correct? If so, how do I go about solving this? Don't you need at least two conditions to solve a second order PDE?

Comment: What is the nature of $\mathcal{R}$, is it a bounded domain?

Comment: @Ian I think it's actually $\mathbb{R}^3$. So the scalar field would be $A:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$

Comment: This is not true for general manifolds: e.g. there can be issues when $S$ is not the boundary of a compact regular domain. 

For instance, consider $M = \mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2 \times \mathbb{R}$ then consider the projection $A(x,y,z) = z$ onto the third factor and $S = \mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2 \times \{0\}$.

Comment: @DavidPerrella Agreed. Really the crucial step in my proof was writing $S$ as the boundary of some bounded set so that I could apply the maximum principle. On a manifold $M$ I guess you would probably also need to require $M$ to be analytic, so that you could conclude that $u$ is analytic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that $S$ is smooth closed surface that is embedded into $\mathbb R^3$. The smoothness assumption can be relaxed to $C^1$. Also, I think the assumption that $S$ is embedded is natural in this context. If you do actually want to consider the case $S$ is not embedded then let me know.

*Proof:*
Since non-orientable surfaces cannot be embedded into $\mathbb R^3$, $S$ must be orientable. Then, by the Jordan-Brouwer separation theorem, $\mathbb R^3 \setminus S$ has two connected components: one bounded which we will call $\Omega$ and one unbounded. For a proof of the Jordan-Brouwer separation theorem in the case $S$ is smooth see [The Jordan-Brouwer Separation Theorem for Smooth Hypersurfaces](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2323445) by Lima and references therein for the $C^1$ case.

Since $A$ is harmonic in $\Omega$ and $A=0$ on $\partial \Omega=S$, by the maximum principle $A \equiv 0$ in $\Omega$. But then, since $A$ is harmonic in all of $\mathbb R^3$, it is analytic in $\mathbb R^3$. Since $A$ vanishes in $\Omega$ and $A$ is analytic in all of $\mathbb R^3$, it follows from unique continuation that $A \equiv 0$ in $\mathbb R^3$.   $\square$

Comment: thanks for the answer. Could you explain the very last sentence? Like what theorems does it follow?

Comment: See the section "Analytic varieties and unique continuation" 
 in https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Real_analytic_function . In this case, the analytic function $u$ and the analytic function $0$ coincide in $\Omega$, so they must be the same